# Updating dictionary using functions

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
def customer_dictionary(balfilename):
    d = {}
    bafile = open(balfilename, 'r')
    for line in bafile:
        dic = line.split()
        d[dic[1]] = [dic[0] , dic[2]]
    return d 
    bafile.close()

def update_customer_dictionary(cdictionary, transfilename):
    transfile = open(transfilename. 'r')
    for line in transfile:
        act, trans = line.strip().split()
        if act in dictionary:
            cdictionary[act][1] += float(trans)
        else:
            cdictionary[act][2] = [act][2]


File 1:
139-28-4313     115    1056.30
706-02-6945     135   -99.06
595-74-5767     143    4289.07
972-87-1379     155    3300.26
814-50-7178     162    3571.94
632-72-6766     182    3516.77
699-77-2796     191    2565.29

File 2:
380     2932.48
192     -830.84
379     2338.82
249     3444.99
466      -88.33
466     2702.32
502     -414.31
554      881.21
```

So I have these two functions, the first creates a dictionary and the second updates the dictionary created in the first using the two files given. I'm not sure if my second function is correct. Can anyone help me out?

[Document for background](https://content.sakai.rutgers.edu/access/content/attachment/369e767d-22a9-47dd-9bb8-51bf744ec6d9/Assignments/c25401b5-052c-4743-83ee-6cb7269d4e37/hw2.pdf)

Comment: How are you not sure? Have you tested it? What happened?

Comment: I tested it and nothing happens, also when I look at the dictionary it isn't updated

Answer (score 0):

First problem in `customer_dictionary`: you close the file after `return`, and the line won't be executed.
The best way to open the file is:

```
with open(balfilename, 'r') as bafile:
    for line in bafile:
        #do stuff
#when done, continue code here, no need to call close()
```

---

Excerpt of dictionary created with `customer_dictionary`:

```
d={'115': ['139-28-4313', '1056.30']}
```

The keys are strings, and the values are lists of two strings.

Then in `update_customer_dictionary` you're trying to do:

```
act="115"
trans="2930.5"
if act in d:
    d[act][1] += float(trans)
else:
    d[act][2] = [act][2]
```

Two problems:

- `d[act][1]` is a string (here '1056.30'). You can't add a string and a float. I'll suggest to change the creation of the dictionnary to have a float, it seems more logical.
- If `act` is not in the dictionary, you need to create a new entry. I don't really understand what you were trying to do with `d[act][2]= [act][2]`, it's not a valid python line.
  You could create a new entry with `d[act]=['unknown',trans]`, but it depends on what you need to achieve.

Comment: I'll try to see what I can do

Comment: But the idea is to add the 2 values in file 2 to the values in the list within the dictionary